# How to indicate polygon vertices with small circles using OpenLayers?

Tags: symbology, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 3 and have more or less implemented everything in my requirements list, except one thing: I am asked to somehow *make the polygon rendering indicate the polygon vertices with small circles*.

In plain words, the desired polygon outline is not just a line - it is a line "adorned" with small circles in all the places where there is a vertex.

How can I do that in OL3? I searched in the ol.style.Style docs (that is, the style I pass via `setStyle` to the `ol.layer.Vector` containing my polygons), but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind OL3 devs [have provided the answer on the GitHub issue list](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3165). You basically use a style's geometry function, that transforms the geometry before projecting it - and in that function, you add your vertices to a MultiPoint geometry. @tsauerwein went as far as creating a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnegwsgx/1/) - many thanks to him for his work.

```
var styleFunction = function() {
  var image = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: null,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'orange', width: 2})
  });
  return [
      new ol.style.Style({
          image: image,
          geometry: function(feature) {
              var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
              return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
          }
      }),
      new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        })
      })
  ];
};
```