# Filter features by geometry in OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2

I have three different type of features on my layers: points, lines, and polygons. I need to create a rule based style based on these three types of layers. So, for example, all points could be green, lines red, and polygons blue. I've been looking through the docs but I can't seem to really find anything that would allow OL2 to do this. Can anyone provide an example, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  What are you having problems with?  A search on setting symbology in OpenLayers provides several results. For example:  https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/728  and  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131117/how-to-indicate-polygon-vertices-with-small-circles-using-openlayers  for example.

Comment: have you considered using OL3?  ol2 is getting a bit old.

Comment: MaryBeth, the problem is I'm not entirely sure how to make a rule that will allow changing style by specific geometry: points, lines, and polygons.

User, that's not my call to make. We're using OL2.